# How to show that the definition of differential of a map between two regular surfaces is independent of the choice of curve?

Tags: differential-geometry

We define for $q \in S$ where $S$ is arbitrary regular surface, the tangent space at $q$ as
$T_q(S) = \{\alpha'(0) \;|\; \alpha :(-\epsilon, \epsilon) \to S \text{ a smooth curve such that } \alpha(0) = q \}$

Let $S_1$ and $S_2$ be two regular surfaces. Let $p \in S_1$ and $f:S_1\to S_2$ be differentiable at $p$. Then we define the differential map as

$Df_p : T_p(S_1) \to T_{f(p)}(S_2)$ defined as following:

Let $w$ in $T_p(S_1) \rightarrow \exists\;$$\alpha : (-\epsilon, \epsilon)\to S_1$ such that $\alpha(0) = p$ and $w = \alpha'(0)$. Now we map $w$ to $(f\circ \alpha)'(0)$, ie, $Df_p(w) = (f\circ \alpha)'(0)$. This is meaningful since, $(f\circ\alpha)(0) = f(p)$ and hence, $(f\circ \alpha)'(0) \in T_{f(p)}(S_2)$

Now what I want to show is that, $Df_p(w) = (f\circ \alpha)'(0) = (f\circ \gamma)'(0)$ for any $\gamma:(-\epsilon, \epsilon)\to S_1$ such that $\gamma(0)= p$ and $\gamma'(0) = w$

How do I show this precisely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially it is because of the chain rule.

For functions $F \colon M \to N$ and $G \colon N \to K$, the differential of the composite map $G \circ F \colon M \to K$ is
$$ d(G \circ F)_m = dG_{F(m)} \circ dF_m $$

In your case, you have
$$ (f \circ \gamma)'(0) = df_{\gamma(0)} \circ \gamma'(0) $$

So if $\gamma'(0) = \alpha'(0)$, then you get $(f \circ \alpha)'(0) = (f \circ \gamma)'(0)$.